# How to make static code analysis aware of an Exception throwing function?

Tags: python, function, exception, warnings

For reasons of readability and re-usability, I have a function that *always* raises a specific exception if called. However, this does not seem to be considered by static code analysis, i.e. I get unnecessary warnings. Is there any good way to avoid these warning, e.g., by making the static code analysis aware of the fact that this function will always raise an exception?

**Minimal working example:**

```
def raise_an_exception():
    raise Exception("...description...")


def foo(arg):
    if arg:
        x = 1
    else:
        raise_an_exception()
    # causes warning "Local variable 'x' might be referenced before assignment":
    return x + 1


def bar(arg):
    if arg:
        x = 1
    else:
        raise Exception("...description...")
    # causes no warning:
    return x + 1
```

**Boundary condition:** I do not want to declare `x` in `foo()` before the `if` statement or set `x` to any value in the `else` code block, or any other workaround like that. It is not necessary in `bar()` and it shouldn't be necessary in `foo()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a `NoReturn` annotation for functions that can't return normally:

```
from typing import NoReturn

def raise_an_exception() -> NoReturn:
    raise Exception("...description...")
```

Static analysis tools that understand type annotations should understand this and not report an error for `foo`.

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work and I think it makes sense it doesn't. The cause for the warning lies not in the return behaviour of `raise_an_exception()`, but in the `else` path in `foo()` where `x` is not set. If it would be clear that `raise_an_exception()` always raises an exception, it would be obvious to the code analysis that the `return x + 1` statement can never be reached after the `else` path had been entered. Therefore, `x` will always be defined when the program reaches the `return x + 1` statement. In `bar()` the code analysis gets it, but in foo() it fails by obscurity.

Comment: @matheburg: I don't know what analysis tool you're using or whether it understands annotations at all, but for a tool that actually understands `NoReturn`, this should work. The analysis doesn't need to know that `raise_an_exception` always raises an exception; all it needs to know is that the function cannot return normally. A function that looped forever or called `os.exec` or something would also be fine.

Comment: Ah, I get it. Sorry, I had the misconception that `-> NoReturn` would annotate that there is no return value, but if the meaning is that there is "no return" from the function, you are 100%ly right.

However, Pycharm CE 2019.2.1 doesn't buy it.

Comment: I have just decided to accept this answer as with `NoReturn` you perfectly answer my question from the title, even though it does not solve my warning issue. The warning seems to be a result of unaware linting...